# How send SVG-element to NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, svg, fetch

I need to send SVG-element to server and then rewrite SVG-file in folder. But i dont understand how to get element in request.body, its "undefined".

[It's my fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahOfA.png)

Answer (score -1):

Well, i find the answer.
You need to [convert svg-element to base64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG5br.png), before send it to server.

On the server you need to [create buffer from request.body and then convert it to string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88YLg.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).